# combining slick queries into single query

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

Using Slick 3.1, how do I combine multiple Queries into a single query for the same type?  This is ***not a join or a union***, but combining query "segments" to create a single query request.  These "segments" can be any individually valid query.

```
val query = TableQuery[SomeThingValid]

// build up pieces of the query in various parts of the application logic
val q1 = query.filter(_.value > 10)
val q2 = query.filter(_.value < 40)
val q3 = query.sortBy(_.date.desc)
val q4 = query.take(5)

// how to combine these into a single query ?
val finalQ = ??? q1 q2 q3 q4 ???

// in order to run in a single request
val result = DB.connection.run(finalQ.result)
```

EDIT:
the expected sql should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "SomeThingValid" WHERE "SomeThingValid"."value" > 10 AND "SomeThingValid"."valid" < 40 ORDER BY "MemberFeedItem"."date" DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you expect as a result. I guess I have to ask: how would you do it in plain SQL?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek updated with example expected sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val q1 = query.filter(_.value > 10)
val q2 = q1.filter(_.value < 40)
val q3 = q2.sortBy(_.date.desc)
val q4 = q3.take(5)
```

I think you should do something like the above (and pass around `Query`s) but if you insist on passing around query "segments", something like this could work:

```
type QuerySegment = Query[SomeThingValid, SomeThingValid, Seq] => Query[SomeThingValid, SomeThingValid, Seq]

val q1: QuerySegment = _.filter(_.value > 10)
val q2: QuerySegment = _.filter(_.value < 40)
val q3: QuerySegment = _.sortBy(_.date.desc)
val q4: QuerySegment = _.take(5)

val finalQ = Function.chain(Seq(q1, q2, q3, q4))(query)
```

Comment: yes, I can add clauses to a query, the goal was to take various queries which have been created and bring them together to generate sql like in the example.

Comment: nice, thanks - that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: the reason I cannot pass around a Query is because the order in which the QuerySegments are generated is non-deterministic but the order in which I build up the query for actual execution is very important.  Using the technique you outlined above, I can take a set of generated segments and assemble them in the correct order when ready for execution.

Answer (score 0):

It's Just a worth remark to mention here from the slick essential book, it seems that you might need to avoid combining multiple queries in one single query.

> Combining actions to sequence queries is a powerful feature of Slick.
> However, you may be able to reduce multiple queries into a single
> database query. If you can do that, you’re probably better off doing
> it.

Answer (score -1):

I've used this "pattern" with slick2.0

```
val query = TableQuery[SomeThingValid]

val flag1, flag3 = false
val flag2, flag4 = true

val bottomFilteredQuery = if(flag1) query.filter(_.value > 10) else query
val topFilteredQuery = if(flag2) bottomFilteredQuery.filter(_.value < 40) else bottomFilteredQuery
val sortedQuery = if(flag3) topFilteredQuery.soryBy(_.date.desc) else topFilteredQuery
val finalQ = if(flag4) sortedQuery.take(5) else sortedQuery
```

Comment: this won't work in my case because the incoming query are a non-deterministic arbitrary set.

Comment: we need a more generic solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think, it should work. But I didn't test it yet.

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]
val filter1: Query[Users, User, Seq] = users.filter(condition1)
val filter2: Query[Users, User, Seq] = users.filter(condition2)
(filter1 ++ filter2).result.headOption
```